# Give focus to the main page in UWP

Tags: uwp

In my application I have logic to be added to bring the application front when calling the LaunchUriAsync method. 
But I could find various options to bring the control to front in the page but I want to focus the page while launching.
Please share the suggestions if you have.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, once you use `LaunchUriAsync` method to launch the app, the app's `OnActivated` event would be fired. You could navigate to `MainPage` in this handler method and call `Window.Current.Activate()` to activate the application window by bringing it to the foreground and setting the input focus to it.

```cs
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnActivated(args);
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }
    }
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Comment: Actually this I have tried but still the application icon is only blinking but it is not bringing the application in foreground.

Comment: @Priya Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to me?